# Prove that a graph $G$ is even iff each of its blocks is even.

Tags: graph-theory

*Definition:* A graph $G$ is even if each of its vertices has even degree.

It is easy to show that $G$ is even if each of its blocks is even.

I was wondering if the converse is true. I started with assuming that this is not the case. Then there are at least two blocks that are not even.

This implies that at least two vertices in each of these blocks have odd degree.

How do I close this argument? Or is there a better proof or counter-example?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a graph to be even?

Comment: Edit made to include it.

Comment: what is block? connected component?

Comment: Are you asking if a block is a connected component?

Comment: @dEmigOd Search for 'block structure of a graph', for example these notes https://people.math.gatech.edu/~thomas/TEACH/6014/lecture7.pdf explain it quite well.

Answer (score 1):

Proof by contracdiction. Assume $G$ is even but not all blocks are. Then there are at least $2$ blocks ($A$ and $B$) with at least $2$ odd degree vertices each. As $A$ and $B$ are distinct blocks there has to exist a cut vertex $v$ in $G$ such that cutting $G$ at $v$ puts $A$ and $B$ into distinct connected components of $G$. As $A$ contains at least two vertices of odd degree, one of them is not equal to $v$. The degree of this vertex is the same before and after cutting at $v$. As we assumed $G$ to be even, this is a contradiction.

Comment: I think this proof has an issue. The vertex with odd degree has the odd degree only in the block. It has an even degree in $G$.

Comment: @Insignificant That's were the contradiction comes from. The only vertex with different degrees is the cut vertex, for all other vertices the degree doesn't change. So it can't be even in $G$ and odd in the block.

Comment: What prevents these two vertices of odd degree in the block, say $A$, from being cut vertices with other blocks? (Or am I totally missing the picture here?)

Comment: @Insignificant They could be cut vertices of other blocks. That's why I didn't compare $G$ to the individual blocks but only cut $G$ at a single cut vertex. Then each of the components could still contain more cut vertices but these weren't touched so their degrees didn't change.

Answer (score 0):

a proof by contradiction on a finite even graph G:

if a block in G has an odd degree vertex, it must have at least one more odd degree vertex (the sum of all degrees must be even). any vertex of even degree in G yet odd degree in it's block must be a cut vertex in G since that's the only way for its degree to be affected by getting rid of all the vertices unrelated to its block. not only it is a cut vertex, it must also have odd degree in another block (its sum of degrees in each of its blocks must be even since it's even in G). this means that each odd vertex in a block induces another block with at least one more odd vertex which is a cut vertex inducing another block with another odd cut vertex, going to infinity. our graph is finite, which leads to a contradiction.